# virtualenv: pip claiming it successfully installs a package, but doesn't

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv

I've been looking at similar questions for about an hour now, but so far no suggestions I've seen have helped me troubleshoot this issue. For example: 
['virtualenv' 'pip install sqlalchemy' but 'pip list' can not see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34937302/virtualenv-pip-install-sqlalchemy-but-pip-list-can-not-see) did not help.

Setup:

1. In my project directory, I typed simply `virtualenv env`
2. Then `source env/bin/activate`
3. I confirmed `pip` and `python` are being run from my venv with
   `which pip` etc.
4. `pip install matplotlib`, and it looks successful:

> ...
>
> Installing collected packages:
>   subprocess32, kiwisolver, numpy, matplotlib
>
> Successfully installed
>   kiwisolver-1.0.1 matplotlib-2.2.2 numpy-1.14.2 subprocess32-3.2.7

5. `python` and then `>> import matplotlib` produces:

> ImportError: No module named matplotlib

I've looked in env/lib/python2.7/site-packages and sure enough, no matplotlib.

Comment: check with `pip freeze` whether the libraries are installed or not

Comment: what version of pip are you on? See if its related to [the recent TLS deprecation for pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49748494/1526703)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW, found the answer: on my amazon EC2 linux, pip was installing to the lib64 directory, not lib. So I just made lib/.../site-packages the --target of pip install and it finally put it there.

Comment: there is a (currently still open) issue for this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4464